# How to combine sheets with whole formatting in python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am using `openpyxl` in python to edit excels. How to combine excels(workbooks) with the whole formatting? Namely copy one entire sheet with the whole formatting after another sheet as following:

[image]

Here it is impossible to conbat data first then edit the format since each excel may has complicate format, charts, e.t.c. I prefer use `openpyxl` to achieve the expected excel, however any libraries are ok if `openpyxl` is not enough to deal with.

Comment: Do you maybe mean *combine* not *combat*?

Comment: @BoarGules yes updated, combine from vertical direction

Comment: Where is your code and data?

Comment: @flywire It is a general question,  the source data is several excel files。 My goal is to know the tool in python (if it exists)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example